# What does numpy.gradient do?

Tags: python, math, numpy

So I know what the gradient of a (mathematical) function is, so I feel like I should know what `numpy.gradient` does. But I don't. The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) is not really helpful either:

> Return the gradient of an N-dimensional array.

What is the gradient of an array? When is `numpy.gradient` useful?

Comment: The docs do give a more detailed description: `The gradient is computed using central differences in the interior and first differences at the boundaries. The returned gradient hence has the same shape as the input array.` Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method.

Comment: As you can define the discrete derivative of a monodimensional array (x[i+1]-x[i])/h in the simplest case, with h typically 1), you can define the discrete gradient; it's often used in image algorithms (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> The gradient is computed using central differences in the interior and
>   first differences at the boundaries.

and

> The default distance is 1

This [means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) that in the interior it is computed as

[image]

where h = 1.0

and at the boundaries

[image]

Comment: Are you sure *h = 1*? Because it means it is *f(x + 0.5) - f(x - 0.5)*, so if we take x = 2 it becomes *f(2.5) - f(1.5)*, if *f* is a 1-d array you can't have non-integer x. Looks like it is *f(x + 1) - f(x - 1)* actually.

Comment: I can't see your formula in dark mode theme.

Answer (score 182):

Also in the documentation<sup>1</sup>:

```
>>> y = np.array([1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16], dtype=np.float)
>>> j = np.gradient(y)
>>> j 
array([ 1. ,  1.5,  2.5,  3.5,  4.5,  5. ])
```

- Gradient is defined as (change in `y`)/(change in `x`).
- `x`, here, is the list index, so the difference between adjacent values is 1.
- At the boundaries, the first difference is calculated. This means that at each end of the array, the gradient given is simply, the difference between the end two values (divided by 1)
- Away from the boundaries the gradient for a particular index is given by taking the difference between the the values either side and dividing by 2.

So, the gradient of `y`, above, is calculated thus:

```
j[0] = (y[1]-y[0])/1 = (2-1)/1  = 1
j[1] = (y[2]-y[0])/2 = (4-1)/2  = 1.5
j[2] = (y[3]-y[1])/2 = (7-2)/2  = 2.5
j[3] = (y[4]-y[2])/2 = (11-4)/2 = 3.5
j[4] = (y[5]-y[3])/2 = (16-7)/2 = 4.5
j[5] = (y[5]-y[4])/1 = (16-11)/1 = 5
```

You could find the minima of all the absolute values in the resulting array to find the turning points of a curve, for example.

---

<sup>1</sup>The array is actually called `x` in the example in the docs, I've changed it to `y` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Can somebody explain why the returned array has the same size as the input array no matter the spacing parameter? I'd expect it to be smaller with larger spacing

Comment: @AlaaM. In the documentation, the example with spacing of `2`, the values are simply half that of the result with no spacing specified. So it looks like it means that the spacing is the distance between each point on the notional x-axis, rather than the default of `1`. So the array will have the same size.

Comment: @SiHa The bottom of this answer should really be in the numpy documentation. This is very helpful, thank you.

Comment: As I understood - np.gradient() can be used to return the first derivative of a signal - is that correct? to compute the second derivative, will it be ok to call np.gradient() twice?
e.g.:  derivative_2 = np.gradient(np.gradient(signal)) ?

Comment: @epifanio I would imagine so, yes, although my mathematics knowledge is very rusty!

Answer (score 27):

Here is what is going on. The Taylor series expansion guides us on how to approximate the derivative, given the value at close points. The simplest comes from the first order Taylor series expansion for a C^2 function (two continuous derivatives)...

- f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x)h+f''(xi)h^2/2.

One can solve for f'(x)...

- f'(x) = [f(x+h) - f(x)]/h + O(h).

Can we do better? Yes indeed. If we assume C^3, then the Taylor expansion is

- f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x)h + f''(x)h^2/2 + f'''(xi) h^3/6, and
- f(x-h) = f(x) - f'(x)h + f''(x)h^2/2 - f'''(xi) h^3/6.

Subtracting these (both the h^0 and h^2 terms drop out!) and solve for f'(x):

- f'(x) = [f(x+h) - f(x-h)]/(2h) + O(h^2).

So, if we have a discretized function defined on equal distant partitions: 
x = x_0,x_0+h(=x_1),....,x_n=x_0+h*n, then numpy gradient will yield a "derivative" array using the first order estimate on the ends and the better estimates in the middle.

**Example 1.** If you don't specify any spacing, the interval is assumed to be 1. so if you call

```
f = np.array([5, 7, 4, 8])
```

what you are saying is that f(0) = 5, f(1) = 7, f(2) = 4, and f(3) = 8. Then

```
np.gradient(f)
```

will be: f'(0) = (7 - 5)/1 = 2, f'(1) = (4 - 5)/(2*1) = -0.5, f'(2) = (8 - 7)/(2*1) = 0.5, f'(3) = (8 - 4)/1 = 4.

**Example 2.** If you specify a single spacing, the spacing is uniform but not 1.

For example, if you call

```
np.gradient(f, 0.5)
```

this is saying that h = 0.5, not 1, i.e., the function is really f(0) = 5, f(0.5) = 7, f(1.0) = 4, f(1.5) = 8. The net effect is to replace h = 1 with h = 0.5 and all the results will be doubled.

**Example 3.** Suppose the discretized function f(x) is not defined on uniformly spaced intervals, for instance f(0) = 5, f(1) = 7, f(3) = 4, f(3.5) = 8, then there is a messier discretized differentiation function that the numpy gradient function uses and you will get the discretized derivatives by calling

```
np.gradient(f, np.array([0,1,3,3.5]))
```

Lastly, if your input is a 2d array, then you are thinking of a function f of x, y defined on a grid. The numpy gradient will output the arrays of "discretized" partial derivatives in x and y.

Comment: I created a video of this explanation... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvP7iZhXqJQ

Answer (score 2):

Think about N-dimensional array as a matrix.
Then gradient is nothing else as *matrix differentiation*

For a good explanation look at [gradient](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html) description in matlab documentation.