# Weird behavior of np.gradient with increased resolution

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to plot cos(x) and it's derivative  -sin(x) on the same plot.
What I do it the following:

```
import numpy as np    
x = np.linspace(0,10,20) #x values: 0-10, 20 values
f = np.cos(x) # function
df = np.gradient(f) # derivative

# plot
plt.plot(f, label ="function")
plt.plot(df, label ="derivative")
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Already here you can see that there is an issue with the amplitude of the derivative. It should be 1, but it's about 0.5.

If I now increase the resolution from 20 to 50 points, the amplitude of the derivative drops even more:

[image]

100 points:

[image]

1000 points:

[image]

**Does anyone know what's going on?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of the default spacing assumed between two consecutive values, which is 1. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24633888/9332187) for details.

In your examples, as you're using `np.linspace`, spacing can be programatically found as

```
sp = np.diff(x)[0]
```

or better yet (thanks to [@Kraigolas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67971076/weird-behavior-of-np-gradient-with-increased-resolution/67971277?noredirect=1#comment124965350_67971277)!)

```
# form the array *and* get the spacing in one shot
x, sp = np.linspace(0, 10, 20, retstep=True)
```

Then,

```
x, sp = np.linspace(0, 10, 2000, retstep=True)
f = np.cos(x)

df = np.gradient(f, sp) # change is here!

# plot
plt.plot(f, label ="function")
plt.plot(df, label ="derivative")
plt.legend()
```

gives

[image]

and similar for other number of points.

Comment: `np.linspace` also takes the argument `retstep`, so that one could write `x, sp = np.linspace(0, 10, 2000, retstep=True)`

Comment: @Kraigolas Oh, thanks for that! Do you mind if I add that to the answer (with proper attribution)?

Comment: That's absolutely fine, happy to help!